# Font type cannot be changed in BIRT pdf

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, fonts, birt

I'm working on java application using BIRT library to create PDF on ubuntu 15.10.

I have to change font (because Polish characters are not displayed well in Times New Roman, which I think is default). On the preview in Eclipse I can choose any font I want and it seems good, but in exported PDF it is still default configuration no matter which font I set.

I was trying to modify **fontsConfig.xml** as well as **fontsConfig_pdf.xml** and **fontsConfig_linux.xml** (placed in **eclipseDir/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts_4.6.0.v201606072122**). 
I changed default font there, and put precise path to Arial font:

```
<font-paths>
    <path path="/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf"/>
</font-paths>
```

but with no success. 
Have you got any idea what else could I do? Maybe I don't properly use these files?

It may be weird, but when I removed these fontsConfig* files  my pdf has generated just the same as when they where in mentioned directory. I read something that these files should be replaced in specified .jar but I cannot find any .jar like it.

Thanks for help